# angularjs object list to collect survey data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of employee objects (available via REST service) and need to collect their attendance (present, absent, on leave). I tried to create a wrapper list to include employee object and attendance using a factory method. But, does not seem like I am doing it right. I can show jus the employee list using ng-repeat, but not the wrapper list. Any hints, how I could make it work?

Comment: any code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dependency chain in order to fetch the employee list and then attendance and then can create an array of employee objects which has the employee data and her attendance. Assuming you have factory methods to fetch the employee list and the attendance, this is how it will look in your controller:

```
var myapp = angular.module("myApp",['urFactory'])
.controller('urController',['urFactory','$scope',function(urFactory,$scope){
$scope.employeeList = [];
var employee = {};
    urFactory.getEmployeeList.success(function(employeeList){

        urFactory.getAttendance.success(function(attendanceData){
            //Logic to match the employee with her attendance and then populate employee object
            //Push employee to scope variable
        });

    });

});
```